# Virtual Function c++

Tags: c++, polymorphism

Hi i have 1 question regarding c++ virtual function...

```
class base{
 public :
    base()  { a=5;}
    int a;
    virtual void print()=0;
    int get(){return a;}
    int get_var(){ a=5;  return a;}
};  

int main(void){
    base *p;
    cout <<"Get Call - No assign\n";
    cout <<"Value is :: "<<p->get()<<endl;
    cout <<"Get Call - assign value\n";
    cout <<"Value is :: "<<p->get_var()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Its o/p is ::
Get Call - No assign
Value is :: 5
Segmentation Fault

I don't understand this behaviour ?
One reason i can think is - as base is abstract class i.e. not having complete   implementation so when i am doing a=5 its getting crashed.
but in first call also i am using a so why it is not getting crashed there
Please help....

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: It is not **that** hard to help a new user with the formant and hint how to do it in the future. -1 to you!

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I usually do that, and I tried to edit myself. *But* not only was the code not formatted, it was all written on one line. *One line, man!*

Comment: I wrote formatted code but they didn't accept so changed this way for acceptance as i needed the same early, i think -4 need not be done

Comment: @Anshulgarg you can type the code plain text, then click on the `{}` icon. Just make sure you have an empty line between normal text and the code.

Answer (score 3):

**Root Cause:**

Your pointer `p` does not point to any valid object and hence the crash(actually it is an ***Undefined Behavior***) when you derefence it by calling a member function on it.

When you declare a pointer just points to any random address, it your responsibility to make it point to a valid object to be able to do anything meaningful with the pointer.

**Solution:**

You need:

```
base *p = new base;
```

or

```
base obj;
base *p = &obj;
```

For either of the above to work, `base` has to be non-abstract class.In your example `base` is an abstract class(*class with at-least one pure virtual function*), for such an class you cannot create any objects of it(*call its constructor*).
So to resolve this problem you need to create a Derived class which derives from your abstract class `base` and then implement the pure virtual function `print()` for your derived class thus making your derived class a concrete class and not an abstract class. Then you can check out the dynamic dispatch at work(*I am guessing that was your aim*)

```
class Derived:public base
{
    public:
        virtual void print()
        {
            //Do some prints
        }
};

int main()
{
    Derived obj;
    Base *ptr = &obj;

    //or

    Base *ptr2 = new Derived;

    //.....Rest of your program as is
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't initialize `base *p;`, therefore calling methods on it is Undefined Behavior (a segfault in your case).

On the other side, it would not be possible to initialize it because `base` is an abstract class. You must provide a definition of `print` in `base` or in a derived class.

Answer (score 1):

> One reason i can think is - as base is abstract class i.e. not having complete implementation so when i am doing a=5 its getting crashed.

No, the crash is caused by dereferencing the unitialised pointer `p` (technically undefined behaviour). As `base` is abstract there is no way to create an instance of it:

```
base b;             // Illegal
base* p = new base; // Illegal
```

and there are no derived concrete classes in the posted code. You need to derive from `base` and implement the pure virtual function `print()`. The [destructor in the `base` class should also be `virtual`](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/virtual-dtors.html).

Answer (score 0):

`p` is an uninitialized pointer.  So doing almost anything with it is Undefined Behavior.

And the answer to "why didn't it crash earlier" is usually "luck" (good or bad, depending on your view).  A program with Undefined Behavior is allowed to do anything at all: seem to work, crash, make your mouse explode, etc.